# Syntax error in 'New'

Tags: vb.net

I was coding sender of emails in vb.net and it is giving Syntax error. Code below:

```
Try
        Dim message As New MailMessage With {
        .Subject = Me.SubjectTxt.Text
    }
        message.To.Add(Me.ReceiverTxt.Text)
        message.From = New MailAddress(Me.EmailTxt.Text)
        message.Body = Me.BodyTxt.Text
        Dim num2 As Integer = (Me.AttachmentListbox.Items.Count - 1)
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Do While (i <= num2)
            Dim item As New Attachment(Conversions.ToString(Me.AttachmentListbox.Items.Item(i)))
            message.Attachments.Add(item)
            i += 1
        Loop
    New SmtpClient(Me.ClientBox.Text) With { _
        .EnableSsl = True, _
        .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Me.EmailTxt.Text, Me.PasswordTxt.Text), _
        .Port = Conversions.ToInteger(Me.PortTxt.Text) _
    }.Send(message)
    Interaction.MsgBox(("Message sent to " & Me.ReceiverTxt.Text), MsgBoxStyle.Information, "SMTP Email Sender")
    Catch exception1 As Exception
        ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1)
        Dim exception As Exception = exception1
        If (Me.ReceiverTxt.Text = Nothing) Then
            Interaction.MsgBox("Please fill up the Receiver.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "You missed something!")
        ElseIf (Me.SubjectTxt.Text = Nothing) Then
            Interaction.MsgBox("Please fill up Subject.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "You missed something!")
        ElseIf (Me.BodyTxt.Text = Nothing) Then
            Interaction.MsgBox("Please fill up the Message Body.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "You missed something!")
        ElseIf (Me.EmailTxt.Text = Nothing) Then
            Interaction.MsgBox("Please fill up the Email for Account Log In.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "You missed something!")
        ElseIf (Me.PasswordTxt.Text = Nothing) Then
            Interaction.MsgBox("Please fill up the Password for Account Log In.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "You missed something!")
        ElseIf (Me.ClientBox.Text = Nothing) Then
            Interaction.MsgBox("Please fill up the Server for basis of SMTP Server.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "You missed something!")
        ElseIf (Me.PortTxt.Text = Nothing) Then
            Interaction.MsgBox("Please fill up the Port to successfully send the email.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "You missed something!")
        Else
            Interaction.MsgBox("Sending Failed", DirectCast(Conversions.ToInteger("SMTP Email Sender"), MsgBoxStyle), Nothing)
        End If
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError()
    End Try
```

The error is in `New SmtpClient`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem of initializers - you don't know which line is a problem. First, break your code into many lines.

```
Dim smtp As New SmtpClient(Me.ClientBox.Text) With { .EnableSsl = True }
smtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Me.EmailTxt.Text, Me.PasswordTxt.Text)
smtp.Port = Conversions.ToInteger(Me.PortTxt.Text)
smtp.Send(message)
```

Generally, your problem was in line starting with new. I just tested it, it doesn't work in vb. Something like this - `(new class()).DoSomething` works in c#. But not in vb. But then again, complex initializers can be detrimental in debugging issues. Now you will be able which line exactly causes the error.

Also, you should add `.Trim()` everywhere

```
  Me.PortTxt.Text.Trim()
```

Comment: @PloxorPB You're welcome. Generally, your problem was in line starting with `new`. I just tested it, it doesn't work in vb. Something like this - (`new class()).DoSomething` works in c#. But not in vb. But then again, complex initializers can be detrimental in debugging issues.

Answer (score 0):

This should have worked:

```
With New SmtpClient(Me.ClientBox.Text.Trim) With {
        .EnableSsl = True,
        .Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Me.EmailTxt.Text.Trim, Me.PasswordTxt.Text.Trim),
        .Port = Conversions.ToInteger(Me.PortTxt.Text.Trim) }
    .Send(message)
End With
```

Note that the .Send is against the outer With block, and the underscores aren't needed. Also added .Trim as the other answer suggested.

Comment: Ok, this is good that you can init object using `With`. But with complex initializers problem remains - you will not know which line is a problem. If you have `new Class() With { .a = true, .b = 10, .c = "string1"}` - this is OK. But when properties are assigned to complex code - this is **bad** for maintaining and debugging code